# Missing gdb symbols in Backtrace?

Tags: java, gdb

I am running this test because I want to see the stacktrace of a program. 
Below is my program:

```
 public class NanoTime {
 public static void main (String[] args) {   
      long StartTime = System.nanoTime();
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {   
         buffer.append("a");  }
      long EndTime = System.nanoTime();
      long totalTime = EndTime-StartTime;
      System.out.println("Total time of calculation ="+ totalTime);   
 }
```

}

Now I am using OpenJDK built with debug-level set to slowdebug and also another one set to fastdebug.
I get this output:

```
[New Thread 0x7ffff7fd3700 (LWP 22532)]

 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7fd3700 (LWP 22532)]0x00007fffe10002b4 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffe10002b4 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000202 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffe1000160 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffff66bd1a9 in execute_internal_vm_tests () at /home/bionix/Openjdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:5128
#4  0x00007ffff7fd2550 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffff6b08bf8 in VM_Version::get_cpu_info_wrapper () at /home/bionix/Openjdk8/hotspot/src/cpu/x86/vm/vm_version_x86.cpp:395
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I am confused at the question marks there, as I expected native methods name.

Note: I am even disabling the JIT Compiler : `gdb --args java -Xint Test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ordinary code, gdb relies on debug information (and to a lesser extent the "linker" symbols) to find the names of functions as it unwinds.  Debugging information is described in various standards, DWARF being the current best one for Linux.  Compilers emit the debugging information that is then read by gdb.

For just-in-time compilers like OpenJDK, there is no agreed-upon solution to emitting debugging information for debuggers to read.  And so, as you've found, gdb generally has no idea what is going on.

In fact, as you can see from your trace, gdb can't even really unwind the entire stack.  That's what this means:

> Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Modern compilers and ABIs tend to require some extra debugging information to unwind as well -- and, again, there's no agreement on how this should work for JIT compilation.  GDB has some heuristics it uses to try to unwind when this information isn't available, but as you can see, they sometimes fail.

So, that's the bad news.

The good news is that gdb provides some ways to write unwinders and debug info readers for JITs.  And, someone is working on this for OpenJDK.  I wasn't able to quickly find the source, but I did find [this thread](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/gdb-and-OpenJDK-td215661.html) which explains it a little.

Comment: With the `-Xint` flag, java should be executing the bytecode via interpreter, so it's surprising that GDB did not land on the interpreter inside JVM.

Comment: I thought OpenJDK did some wacky thing like generate an assembly interpreter during VM initialization.  So it isn't necessarily inconsistent.  Though I did miss that point.

Answer (score 0):

This is because jvm is using template interpreter. For that interpreter java bytecode handlers are translated into machine instructions for the current platform during  start time. Still you can get the full stacktrace, more info: [template interpreter demo](http://progdoc.de/papers/Joker2014/joker2014.html#(5))

There is also cpp interpreter and that is the interpreter you would expect to see in your stacktraces. But cpp interpreter is not supported anymore and is only available with zero jvm variant.

Also there is an [article](https://medium.com/@metebalci/demystifying-the-jvm-jvm-variants-cppinterpreter-and-templateinterpreter-9f7d5b781850) about the interpreters.